# CIColorClamp not working correctly in OS X El Capitan

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, core-image, osx-elcapitan

I am using Swift to do some video processing. After upgrading to El Capitan (and Swift 2) my code broke. I traced an error down to the CIFilter function CIColorClamp. This function is supposed to clamp the pixel values, but in fact messes up the image extent.

```
    let _c:CGFloat = 0.05
    let minComp = CIVector(x:_c, y:_c, z:_c, w: 1)
    let maxComp = CIVector(x:1, y:1, z:1, w: 1)
    let clamp: CIFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorClamp")!
    print("clamp-in \(image.extent)")
    clamp.setDefaults()
    clamp.setValue(image, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    clamp.setValue(minComp, forKey: "inputMinComponents")
    clamp.setValue(maxComp, forKey: "inputMaxComponents")
    print("clamp-out \(clamp.outputImage!.extent)")
```

The code above produces the output:

```
> clamp-in (6.0, 6.0, 1268.0, 708.0)
CoreAnimation: Warning! CAImageQueueSetOwner() is deprecated and does nothing. Please stop calling this method.
> clamp-out (-8.98846567431158e+307, -8.98846567431158e+307, 1.79769313486232e+308, 1.79769313486232e+308)
```

The fact that this call produces an internal warning does not instill confidence either!

Can anyone confirm this behavior? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I also ran into this Problem. The extent was always set like this

> -8.98846567431158e+307, -8.98846567431158e+307, 1.79769313486232e+308, 1.79769313486232e+308

but then I tried calling `filter.debugDescription` and recognized that in the extent in the sourceImage is given properly.

Here's my workaround. Because I use different filters, I ask if the filters name is `'CIColorClamp'` and then I set the extent used in the `CGImageRef` to the values from the original image.

```
var extent = filteredImage.extent
if filter.name == "CIColorClamp" {
    extent = sourceImage.extent
}
let cgImage:CGImageRef = context.createCGImage(filteredImage, fromRect: extent)
UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage(CGImage: cgImage), 1.0).writeToFile(...)
```

Before that fix I always had an Crash cause the `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` could not be created, cause of the wrong extent values.

So it looks like that the extent is not transferred to the filtered image.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the problem. I fixed it simply by cropping the returned image to the original image rect (Objective-C code):

```
if ([filter.name isEqualToString:@"CIColorClamp"]) {
    image = [image imageByCroppingToRect:sourceImage.extent];
}
```